# Add data based on column in DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

All of the information is below, but the main idea is this:
I want to be able to show or hide columns in my Repeater Control based on the event number. For example, Event 5 will show certain columns like Name and Address and hide other columns like Phone and Email. I am thinking I could somehow assign a 1 or 0 to note which ones should be used or not used. Event 5 using Name would be 51, not using Phone would be 50. How to implement this, not sure.

Information:
I am building a web app for conferences. There will be admin who can create web forms for people to register for a conference. I want the admin to have control over which fields they collect for their registrants. Just for testing purposes, the fields they can collect include First Name, Last Name, Address, Email, Phone, and Shirt Size

```
Table: Registrant
Columns: Id, EventId, FirstName, LastName, Address, Email, Phone, ShirtSize
```

Depending on the conference, there will be certain fields not used. For example, conference 1 wants to collect ShirtSize data, but conference 2 doesn't want to collect ShirtSize data.

I am using a Repeater control in Visual Studio that currently generates all columns from Registrant.

ASP

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MyColumn") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="textTest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

C#

```
   DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("MyColumn", typeof(string));


        using (SqlConnection sqlConn2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlConn2.Open();

            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand())
            {
                sqlCmd2.Connection = sqlConn2;
                sqlCmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                sqlCmd2.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS MyColumn FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName");
                //sqlCmd2.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS MyColumn FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName" AND SHOW = @Show);
                sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@TableName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "registrant";
                //sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@Show", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "show";
                sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd2.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                    {
                        DataRow tableRow = table.NewRow();
                        tableRow["MyColumn"] = sqlReader["MyColumn"].ToString();
                        table.Rows.Add(tableRow);
                    }
                    Repeater1.DataSource = table;
                    Repeater1.DataBind();
                }

                sqlConn2.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I want a way to display the correct columns depending on the event. For example, if the event is 5, then show FirstName, LastName, and Address. I want to implement this in my database itself, not via my C# code because this will be a big web app when all is done. I think maybe a trigger of some sort, but I am new to database and not completely sure. I am using SQL Server Management Studio. In my C# code, I commented out 2 lines that could possibly be used once I figure out the database structure for my problem.

Comment: Use stored procs or views to control the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a separate table to control column settings for each column, here is an example table:

```
CREATE TABLE ColumnSettings
(
    EventId int,
    TableName nvarchar(50),
    ColumnName nvarchar(50),
    Visible bit
)
```

When you are querying the data for your repeater control you can also query this new table for the settings:

```
select
ColumnName
from ColumnSettings
where EventId = @event_id
and TableName = @table_name
and Visible = 1
```

And use the results of this query to decide if you want to add the column to the data for the repeater control or not